# How to search object with array of inputs AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used the AngularJS filter to search objects and even used the deep search with the $, however partial searches like the below never return the result that I would expect, I can split the search input into an array using .split(" ") though I do not know how to correctly pass this array to the filter.

I have tried to define my own filter with no success.

Data:

```
[
  { 
    Description: "test Description",
    Color: "Blue",
    Size: "Large"
  }, { 
    Description: "aest 2",
    Color: "orange",
    Size: "Large"
  }
  , { 
    Description: "test 3",
    Color: "black",
    Size: "small"
  }
]
```

- **Search input -> expected behavior**
- "tes blu" -> return one result
- "te desc" -> return one result
- "purple" -> return zero results

Any advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

I am using AngularJS: v1.3.13

code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/j3NqCtO1qHJrMuj6y2nv?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/j3NqCtO1qHJrMuj6y2nv?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I solved it: http://plnkr.co/edit/W66NxRlh8deRUh6Uxpor?p=preview

```
var App = angular.module("App",[]);
  App.controller("testCtrl",function($rootScope,$scope){

    $scope.testObjects = [
      { 
        Description: "test Description",
        Color: "Blue",
        Size: "Large"
      }, { 
        Description: "aest 2",
        Color: "orange",
        Size: "Large"
      }
      , { 
        Description: "test 3",
        Color: "black",
        Size: "small"
      }
      ];

     $scope.Search = "";


    $rootScope.ScoreThings =  function(object , inputArray){

          var result = 0;

          for (var x = 0; x < inputArray.length; x++)
          {
                    angular.forEach(object, function(value, key) {
                      if (value.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputArray[x].toLowerCase()) > -1)
                      {
                        result ++;
                      } 

                    });     

           }

          return result;
      }


  });


App.filter('SearchFilter2', function ($rootScope) {

  return function (items, inputString) {

    var filtered = [];
    var inputArray = inputString.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
    {
      if ($rootScope.ScoreThings(items[i], inputArray) > (inputArray.length / 1.2) ) 
      {
          filtered.push(items[i]);
      }
    }

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

use it in your view like:

```
     <tr ng-repeat="testObject in testObjects | SearchFilter2 : Search ">
```